# Find value of javascript parameters from other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yql

Suppose I have a javascript on one page containing the following:

```
findTYP('first').setup({
 "list" : [
      {
         "sources" : [
            {
               "file" : "http://url.com/lorem",
            },
            {
               "file" : "http://url.com/ipsum",
            }
         ],

.
etc.
.
```

From another site, what would be a way (anyway, even dirty ones) to find the values of the URLs using Jquery, PHP, Javascript, Ajax,etc.

When the browser loads, it should get the values and use them on the page. I've tried using JSONP method by YQL, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: you can parse the json ?

Answer (score 1):

JSONP and YQL wont work with this. Javascript blocks external domain calling coz of safety issues. you should pass the url to your server side code and then use something like CURL in php for downloading the page on your server, parse the html or whatever you want on server side and send back to your client.

Comment: Hmm, but would the HTML generated be from the User or the server?

Comment: when your server will call the url using CURL, the remote server will render the page just like you open the url in your browser.

Comment: suppose my server is in US and the user is in Canada, if i render Google.com, what version would it be? I need exactly what the user sees in his browser, ie, the Canadian version in this case.

Comment: In that case you have to read the XHR header of your ajax request to the server. And then set the headers of your CURL request accordingly and then request or download the page. In that case you'll get the same page as the user sees on the browser.